# What is the area of this Trapezium

Tags: ratio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mibx1.jpg)There is a triangle that contains 3 triangles and a trapezium. The area of these triangles are respectively 4, 7, and 14. What is the area of the Trapezium?

Comment: It would help if you provided a picture.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this without more detail about the configuration. Do you have an image?

Comment: What have you tried so far? To help you we need to understand your thought processes as well as the problem itself (as others have said, we'll need a picture).

Answer (score 0):

In the figure below (not drawn to scale), break the trapezium into two triangles with areas $x$ and $y$.
[image]
Notice that segment $FC$ is has twice the length of segment $DF$, since triangle $\triangle FCA$ has twice the area of triangle $\triangle DFA$, and these triangles have the same 'height' relative to their bases $FC$ and $DF$. Observing that segments $FC$ and $DF$ are also bases for triangles $\triangle ECF$ and $\triangle DEF$, we deduce $x=2$.

To compute $y$, notice that the area of triangle $\triangle BED$ bears the same relationship to the area of triangle $\triangle DEA$ as does triangle $\triangle BCD$ to triangle $\triangle DCA$. (We deduce this by considering the segments $BD$ and $DA$ as bases for these triangles.) That is:
$$\frac y{x+7}=\frac{BD}{DA}=\frac {y+x+4}{7+14}.$$
Plug in $x=2$ and solve for $y=\frac92$.